# Stream mp3 Audio from WebServer to NodeMCU ESP8266?

Tags: audio, lua, mp3, esp8266

I have a ESP8266 module with NodeMCU firmware installed. Now I want to stream an mp3 audio file from my web server to be outputted on a speaker connected to the ESP8266.

I found [this project](https://github.com/espressif/esp8266_mp3_decoder) which streams mp3 but uses FreeRTOS.

**How do I connect an external mp3 decoder to the ESP8266 using NodeMCU and which mp3 decode should I use?**

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it via arduino ide.
You need to stream mp3 via VLC or winamp shoutcast.
But first you need get to some hardware which is mp3 decoder : VS1053 MP3 Deceoder(SPI Bus).
Than Someone did this project with ethernet interface so you can do with EPS8266 using arduino ide.
So check this project before you start : http://www.serasidis.gr/circuits/Arduino_WebRadio_player/Arduino_WebRadio_player.htm